# In which comic did Spider-Man remove his mask to rescue a girl?

Tags: story-identification, marvel, spider-man

I saw a snippet from a Spider-Man comic in a post someone made online one time. In this comic, Spider-Man is attempting to rescue a little girl from a height, or a fire. She's afraid of his mask, so he takes it off to reassure her.

The art was done in what looks like a newer style; I'd guess it was probably written in the last couple of decades or so.

Comment: That happens in *The Amazing Spider-man* movie; are you sure it was a comic you're thinking of?

Comment: Well, it was on a thread featuring a bunch of clips of moments in comic books, and I distinctly remember the illustration. Also, he was initially in full costume (hence having to remove the mask), and there was a risk of his being discovered, as somebody else (maybe a police officer?) was nearby. That said, maybe it was partially inspired by the film (or vice versa).

Comment: Strangely enough, reading the title reminded me of this Batman Beyond episode: https://youtu.be/xGEtVQh4N74?t=220

Answer (score 12):

This may be the official [tie-in comic](http://marvel.com/comics/issue/49194/the_amazing_spider-man_the_movie_adaptation_2014_1) to [*The Amazing Spider-Man*](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0948470/?ref_=fn_al_tt_1) movie:

[image]

[image]

> The Lizard was tossing card around like they were toys, and it was all I could do to save them (thanks to the combo of my super-strength and artificial webbing)
>
> **Spider-man:** Whoa! Whoa! Whoa! Hey! Not cool! You're just going to throw a car and run?
>
> I wanted to go after him. But I heard screams for help.
>
> **Father:** My boy Jack is still in the car!
>
> So I did what I had to do.
>
> **Jack:** Daddy, help!
>
> The boy was terrified. I guess I broke superhero rule #1 by taking off my mask. But I had to do something to calm him down.
>
> **Spider-man:** See, Jack? I'm just a normal guy. Here, put [my mask] on. It'll make you brave. *[Jack puts on the mask]* Okay, see? Now I want you to reach out to me as I climb in. Now! grab my arm!
>
> *[Spider-man zips out of the falling car, holding on to Jack]*
>
> **Father:** Oh, thank you...thank you. Who are you?
>
> I felt strange but exhilarated -- I was starting to to realize that I really could make a difference.
>
> **Spider-man:** I'm... Spider-man.

The child in danger is a boy, not a girl, and there doesn't appear to be imminent danger of discovery (as was mentioned in a comment on the question), but it otherwise seems to fit.

Comment: Did he take the mask back off the kid as soon as they were free of the wreckage? Harsh...

Comment: @Richard well, Spiderman needs some bravery as well

Comment: Did he rescue anyone else out of all those other cars, or just the boy? https://youtu.be/LiV7Xs2cvqg?t=56s